# Can't find RegionIntersection of DelaunayMesh

Tags: regions, computational-geometry, mesh

I want to find the RegionIntersection of two DelaunayMesh (given below), but the evaluation never ends. Though when I plot them, their regions are valid and shown to intersect. Why is this?

```
reg1 = DelaunayMesh[{{0.54, 0.26, 0.11}, {0.54, 0.26, 0.1}, {0.54, 0.185, 0.185}, {0.54, 0.15333333333333332, 0.15333333333333332}, {0.4, 0.4, 0.11}, {0.4, 0.4, 0.1}, {0.30333333333333334, 0.30333333333333334, 0.30333333333333334}, {0.25, 0.25, 0.25}}]

reg2 = DelaunayMesh[{{0.5, 0.3, 0.15}, {0.5, 0.3, 0.1}, {0.5, 0.225, 0.225}, {0.5, 0.16666666666666666, 0.16666666666666666}, {0.4, 0.4, 0.15}, {0.4, 0.4, 0.1}, {0.31666666666666665, 0.31666666666666665, 0.31666666666666665}, {0.25, 0.25, 0.25}}]

RegionIntersection[reg1, reg2]
```

[image]

Comment: Why not just find the intersection of the convex hulls of the two point sets?

Comment: @J.M. Because I want to find `RandomPoint`s in the intersection which is not permitted by `ConvexHullMesh`, and I'm curious as to why intersection of `DelaunayMesh`s works for other pairs but not this one.

Comment: The example doesn't work for me in 11.2, but it works for me in (the soon to be released) 11.3.

Comment: @ChipHurst So it's a bug then? When will 11.3 be released?